# ¿Cómo leer entre lineas en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

tengo el siguiente problema,
necesito buscar entre 2 lineas especificas en un archivo .txt, cada una de esas lineas tiene la misma palabra que las diferencia del resto por ejemplo el archivo es compuesto de:

```
    LECTURA 12-13-14
    linea1
    linea2
    linea3
    lineaN
    LECTURA 13-13-14
```

Y necesito leer " linea1, linea2, linea3, lineaN "
 Este es el codigo que tengo hasta el momento.

```
    nuevo_ciclo=[]
    linea_ciclo=[]
    nueva_hora=[]
    nuevo_dia=[]
    registro = open("archico.txt","r")      
    lineas = registro.readlines()
    for linea in lineas:        
            for i in linea.split("\n"): 
                if i.find("palabra")>=0:        
                    for linea_encontra in i.split("\t"):
                        for linea_encontra_1 in linea_encontra.split(" "):
                            linea_ciclo.append(linea_encontra_1)
    ciclo1=linea_ciclo[1]
    ciclo2=linea_ciclo[4]
    a=ciclo1.split("-")
    b=ciclo2.split("-")
    c=ciclo1[0]
    d=ciclo2[0]
    for lineas in range(c,d):
        print(lineas)
```

Comment: Ya que `for linea in lineas:` te devuelve una línea de cada vez, no tiene sentido que hagas luego un `linea.split("\n")`, pues no habrá retornos de carro dentro de una línea (si no, no sería una línea). Y hacer un `split("\t")` para luego dentro otro `split(" ")` puede sustituirse por un solo `.split()`, sin parámetro, que divide por cualquier blanco. Por otro lado todos esos split no están haciendo realmente lo que pides, que en principio es solo guardar las líneas entre dos marcadores dados.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que abusas mucho del `.split()`. Haces un `.split("\t")` seguido de un `.split(" ")`. De tu texto de ejemplo no se deduce que tengas columnas separadas por tabuladores y que cada columna la dividas por espacios en blanco. Voy a darte una solución a la pregunta, aunque me da que haces más cosas. El último `print(lineas)` no lo entiendo.

Dos cuestiones previas:

1. Para buscar un texto en otro, la forma más simple es usando el operador `in`, o el método `.startswith()` si lo que queremos es averiguar si empieza por esa palabra:

```
    "palabra" in linea
    linea.startswith("palabra")
```

2. Es frecuente olvidarse cerrar el fichero de lectura. El patrón recomendado en python para evitar este olvido es usar la sentencia `with` para trabajar con ficheros:

```
    with open("archivo.txt","r") as registro:
        ...
```

Sospecho que necesitas extraer más información que la que indicas. Lo mejor será crear una clase para almacenar la información de cada ciclo. Luego ya la completas para procesar las cabeceras como necesites:

```
class Ciclo:
    def __init__(self, cabecera, lineas):
        self.cabecera = cabecera
        self.lineas = lineas
```

Así tendríamos

```
# lista para guardar los ciclos
lista_ciclo = []

with open("archivo.txt","r") as registro:
    cabecera = ""
    lineas = []
    for linea in registro:
        if linea.startswith("LECTURA"):
            if cabecera != "":
                ciclo = Ciclo(cabecera, lineas)
                lista_ciclo.append(ciclo)

            # nuevo ciclo
            cabecera = linea
            lineas = []
        else:
            lineas.append(linea)
    else:
        # registrar las últimas líneas del fichero
        if cabecera != "":
            ciclo = Ciclo(cabecera, lineas)
            lista_ciclo.append(ciclo)
```

Comment: Estas almacenando la cabecera + la linea + la linea, lo que significa aproximadamente 3 veces el espacio en memoria necesario.

Comment: Creo que está corregido. Gracias.